# Model Inheritance or Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django, model

I'm sure there are probably several ways to do what I am achieving, but have run into some problems. I have a "Member" model and I'm also trying to add a "Dependent" model that inherits some fields and data from the parent (Member) but also has some of the same fields, but their own data. What would be the best way to achieve this? ForeignKey, OneToOne, or ManyToMany, or is it even possible?

Example:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    age = models.DateField()

class Dependent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128) (different name)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128) (same address as Member)
    age = models.DateField() (different age)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't a `is_dependent` flag here be the best option? So a `BooleanField` that indicates if it is a dependent. Furthermore the 1-1, m2m, and `ForeignKey` have different quantifiers, so this is not a matter of "design" but a fundamental modeling difference.

Comment: ForeignKey seems like the best idea because inheritance doesn't make much sense here and this is  probably not a one to one relation or many to many.

Comment: If on the other hand a `Member` can have zero, one, or multiple `Dependent`s, a `ForeignKey` will model a many-to-one relation. You can also use an *abstract* model that contains the shared fields.

Comment: But the above is unclear, so I think you should provide more info: how does a `Dependent` relate to a `Member`? Can a member have zero, one, or more `Dependent`s? Can a `Dependent` have zero, one, or more `Member`s? *Is* a `Dependent` a `Member`?

Comment: You should really make the semantic relation between a `Member` and a `Dependant` clearer, as asked by @WillemVanOnsem. Otherwise, this question cannot be properly answered.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. A member can have zero, one, or many dependents. The dependent needs to be tied to the member. I will be adding a form on the member itself to add a dependent. the "member_number" field will be the same but adding -1 or -2 or -3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Dependent` has the same fields as `Member` but has some extra fields, you can make both `Dependent` and `Member` inherit an [abstract base class](https://godjango.com/blog/django-abstract-base-class-model-inheritance/) (thanks to @WillemVanOnsem for pointing it out) to avoid redefining the same fields, and since `Member` and `Dependent` have a parent-child relationship, you should add a foreign key to `Member` as an additional field in the `Dependent` model. You can also override the `save` method of `Member` to make it sync the addresses of its `Dependent` children when saved.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    age = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Member(Person):
    def save(self):
        super().save()
        self.dependents.exclude(address=self.address).update(address=self.address)

class Dependent(Person):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='dependents')
    extra_field = ...
```

Comment: But by inheriting a non-abstract model, you already have an "implicit" `parent` relation, except that it is more a `OneToOneField`. See: https://godjango.com/blog/django-abstract-base-class-multi-table-inheritance/

Comment: The implicit parent here is not really a parent but just the base identity of the heir. A foreign key is still needed to denote a real parent-child relationship.

Comment: @bihsing: but where in the question do you read about a many-to-one. Here the parent-child relation can refer to two things: (a) the inheritance, or (b) the fact that a `Dependent` has a many-to-one to `Member`. Furthermore by using such inheritance, we will require extra `JOIN`s to fetch data. Although inheritance is covered in Django, it is typically not good practice.

Comment: Indeed. I simply inferred the many-to-one relationship by the meaning of the word "dependent" (and that it should share the same address as the parent). It makes sense to me from the perspective of its probable use in the real world.

Comment: Good point about the inherent deficiency of a non-abstract model inheritance. I've updated my answer to use an abstract base class instead. Thanks for pointing it out.